# Rails Ajax pagination/infinite scroll - keeping it fast and efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, infinite-scroll, kaminari

I have a pretty classic case of ajax pagination, where I paginate my records (using Kaminari) and when the user hits a "load more" button the next page/set of records should be loaded and inserted via ajax.

The problem is that most examples I see are very simplistic, with an index action that looks like this:

```
def index
  users = User.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

And the pagination (or load more) button just keeps calling that index action, with the next `page` param.

The problem is, my index action has a **LOT** more to it than that, and I don't want to run all that code when all I want is the next page of user records - it's slow and needless.

In terms of convention, what's the cleanest way to handle this? My thought was to have another method *in addition* to `index` like so:

```
def load_more_users
  users = User.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

And the pagination calls that one instead of index. However, is there a tidy way to do a conditional in the index action, for example check for the existence of `params[:page]` and `if request.xhr?`?

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a `respond_to` block for this

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
     # Existing index controller code
     # Will render the existing template
  }
  format.js {
     users = User.page(params[:page]).per(10)
     render json: users # Or render a partial
  }
end
```

Ajax will hit the `format.js` block, the initial page load will hit the `format.html` block.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. I think that would work, but convention-wise I haven't seen it used like that. I always see a `respond_to` block at the end of a method to deal with routing and redirect logic.

Comment: Convention-wise, all this is doing is executing a block of code given a certain request format. As you said, you could accomplish the same thing with an if else statement, this is just more clear I think. We tend to use this format a bit in one of our apps, so if it's "wrong" I would hope my boss would point that out to me. :)

Comment: @scilence I can agree this is the way to go however I would use `format.json` since this renders JSON. `js` is usually for Javascript code in a "js.erb" view for execution on the client. [Rails Example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)

Comment: @engineersmnky You're absolutely right. For example purposes I assumed the OP was making a plain ajax request to the same endpoint as the html. If the ajax request doesn't hit `/path.json`, but is a xhr request to `/path`, it will hit `format.js` and not `format.json`. What we're rendering in the format block isn't important, it's how we're requesting it.

Comment: I completely understand what we are rending in not important I just feel like the dual use of `format.js` (which btw is extremely prevalent) is a bastardization. One of my favorite aspects of ruby is its definitive nature and `json` is clearly more definitive to what is desired

Comment: @engineersmnky Right, I guess it just wasn't relevant to the question at hand to bring up. I just wanted it to be clear that _something_ needs to be rendered.